# New to Android: debugging

Tags: android, android-debug

So I am almost totally new to Android Development. I played around with it a long time ago in the Froyo days but it's so different now and it has been so long that I am basically new to the whole thing.

So, I am trying to get a Camera application started to play around with the API and see what I can do. I generated a Fullscreen App using the Android Studio Wizard and then copied the Camera application example code from the Android website.

The application builds without any problems, it installs to my Nexus 4 emulator fine, but when I try to run it on the emulator it simply opens and closes again immediately saying "Unfortunately, Cam has stopped"

I'm not going to make you read through all the code I have so far, rather my question is not so much what is my problem but just what can I do, as a newcomer, to determine the problem? I have tried adding an alert dialog to the `onCreate` method of my Activity Class using the following code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setMessage("Begun");
alert.show();
```

However nothing happens. I just get the same unhelpful message that the application has unfortunately stopped.

Comment: Please post your logcat showing the error log. Rather, that's what you can do to figure it out. Should give you an error, then a ways down will say "Caused by...", that's your problem.

Comment: go to the logcat window, when your application crash you will see a text which will say to you what happens. It's the stacktrace.

Comment: Don't appear som change in the screen?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about logcat... that's really helpful. However, the information seems somewhat limited. It tells me there is a NullPointerException, but nothing about which variable has caused it or what line it occured on, just the method it occured in. `java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.luketim.cam.cam.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:34)`

Comment: Oh, a few lines up I am told there is a permission failure on the Camera permissions. What could be causing this?

Comment: Okay, now I am getting the following message from nothing to do with my code but seemingly the cause of another NullPointerException: `gralloc_alloc: Mismatched usage flags: 328 x 546`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot AlerDialog.Builder create();

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setMessage("Begun");
alert.create().show();
```

Comment: it will do the same thing, just don't show the dialog (create)

Comment: It should be `alert.create().show();` if we're going this route to show the dialog.

Comment: create() is not necessary, show() will create and show the dialog in one method.